# AWS storage architecture help is needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have recently joined a company who have a single working AWS environment, manually created in the console, running a few Java apps that use data in an S3 bucket using a Boto-esque library.

I want to use Terraform create arbitrary clones of the environment on demand, in different AWS accounts, and I am stuck on copying big S3 buckets (~600Gb of files).

How have other people solved this problem in the past?